# Multiple case insensitive like comparisons in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-like, case-insensitive

I am trying to create a book store search field that matches keywords in a book's title, subtitle, and author columns. I can get a single case insensitive like statement to work, but it seems to not work when I try under multiple columns. Can anyone help me find what is wrong? Or is there an easier way to accomplish this?

```
    $getbooks= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM books WHERE (
    LOWER(title) LIKE LOWER('%,".$_GET['search'].",%') 
    OR LOWER(author) LIKE LOWER('%,".$_GET['search'].",%') 
    OR LOWER(subtitle) LIKE LOWER('%,".$_GET['search'].",%')
    ) 
    AND status='1' 
    ORDER BY id DESC");
```

Comment: mysql is case insensitive by default, unless you specify a `binary` comparison, or are using a case-sensitive collation... And you are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). Enjoy having your server pwn3d.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this doesn't work? Are you getting an error? The wrong result? If so, on what data?

Comment: @Mureinik sorry, I forgot to mention the results. `mysql_error()` is returning nothing. I am getting no errors so I imagine that it is the logic that is incorrect. There are about 80 books in the store so when it comes to matching, I know a few keywords would return multiple results.

Comment: spencer never code like this bud. see sql injection attacks, this amazing post by me (will provide later), and solr. my link to follow, after you focus on fixing the sql injection attack

Comment: @DrewPierce I imagine you just throw in a few sql escapes and recommend I change to mysqli. This book store is far from release. No worries.

Comment: let's ignore sql injection for a moment. use `text` columns fulltext search, and myIsam engine at least for the obvious table(s), and when fulltext search stinks, move on to solr. now back to sql injection .... :>  (which you know so start there)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the commas in your LIKE clauses:

e.g., instead of :

`LIKE LOWER('%,".$_GET['search'].",%')`

do this:

`LIKE LOWER('%".$_GET['search']."%')`

Otherwise you will only match on items that are surrounded by commas!

You should also give some serious credence to the comments indicating SQL Injection attack vulnerability.

Comment: it's like having a kitchen burst into flames but focusing on taking out the trash

Comment: And this is why you don't copy and paste old code, rewrite every time....you never look to change the most obvious things. Thank you!

Comment: Spencer if you think this is the answer to your real problem, i say deploy it (no offense to user700390, nothing to do with you or your answer).

Comment: @DrewPierce My reasoning here is that this looks like a homework assignment and the OP has made a genuine attempt to solve the problem himself; yes SQL Injection is important but I believe this answer is appropriate based on the guidelines for this site.

Comment: i agree 700390. but sadly it is prob not a hw assignment. thus is the state of global software dev